# Unity Editor GUI text size limit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm developing some tools for Unity (not for a game, just editor plugins, thus everything is happening inside an `EditorWindow`). One of these tools has to include an editor of text data files, which can be very long.

Unity has a well-known problem: for some reason, even in the editor text is drwn using polygons, each letter has four vertices, and as there is a limit of **65535** vertices per object, there can only be **16383** characters in a text.

In a "view mode" it's rather easy to solve: I've divided the **very long string** by line breaks and have put each in it's own `EditorGUI.TextArea`.

But, in the edit mode it has to be done like this:

```cs
string myText = "more-than-16383-characters";

void OnGUI()
{
   myText = EditorGUI.TextArea(myText);
}
```

So, even if I divide my text into chunks (e.x., into pages), there will be a mess: there is no control of cursor position, exact start and end of typing and so on. Text will be cut in unexpected places and parts of the words will be moved back and forth between pages, multiplying in the process.

For now I just catch the limit, stop input in place (and it can be in the middle of the word), and show a message like "you've exceeded the limit, please continue editing in any external editor". But it is obviously morbidly not very cool.

So, the question is: how to edit a **very long text** in the `EditorWindow`?

Comment: I have 80.000 characters in a `EditorGUILayout.TextArea` and it works fine - displaying long texts seems not even an issue - what does **not** work is selecting anything beyond the `16335`th character ... though clicking and setting the caret still works but it isn't displayed ^^ Since Unity hasn't the ambition to be a good text editor I would actually rather recommend exactly this: Use an external editor since they are most of the times way more efficient and powerful.